What's this horror movie with teens driving into an Amish town?
I can't think of this one scary movie; it was shot documentary-style, like "The Blair Witch Project".

It's about a group of teens driving around.
They go to an Amish-type town and start seeing weird, paranormal
things.
They dare a friend to go into a house and at least bring a pillow back.
The ending shows them getting all cut up and eaten by these Amish people. 

I thought the title was something like "June 2nd" or "July 2nd" but I couldn't find anything on it. The cover or poster showed a cross.   
I really want to see it again. The last time I posted this question, I got some suggestions, and I know for sure the title was a date. 
If someone could please help me that'd be awesome.

I've changed your post title to add more information. I've also put in the correct tags ('identify-this-movie' and 'horror').

No worries. A decent title and tag just makes it easier for everyone :-)


June 9 (2008)
From this site, here's a synopsis:

The film is about a group of  bored high-schoolers who, during one
  week in June, decide to take a camera along to document themselves
  as they pull pranks on the residents of a neighboring town.



In between harassing the locals, the group also investigate the small
  town’s local legends. It's all fun and games until they start
  pissing off more and more locals, and their boredom-fueled antics
  turn deadly.


And from one of the reviews on IMDb:

Little by little, weird things begin to happen. For example, on
  one trip, they look in a house and see several Amish-looking men
  just standing and staring ominously.

Read more about the movie here, here and here. Watch the trailer here.
~ Screenshots taken from YouTube trailer

Glad to help :-)
